# Error no operator "<" matches these demands

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that asks for a two word password and checks to see if it's right. I get an error saying "no operator "<" matches these demands" can anyone help?

```
int main()
{
    string pass = "pass word";
    string x;

    for (x = "pass word"; x < 3, x--)
    {
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cout << "Enter password" << endl;
        if (x == "pass word")
        {
            cout << "right" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            getline(cin, x);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Also: Data type `string` does not fit your comparisons with integer. Better use `int`.

Comment: There are lots of error like at ln 7 comparision between int and string, at 9 instead of comparing you are assigning values. I would advise learn about data types, comparison, assignment, loops then start doing this problem. You will definitely sovle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( x = 'pass word')
```

This is attempting to set the x variable to “pass word” instead of comparing it to that string.

Instead do

```
if ( x == 'pass word')
```

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with the quotes in that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

It you are working on string then use Comparison operators "==" or "!="
and if you working on numbers (integers) then use logical operators "<", ">","<=",  ">=" or "!=".
Hope this will helps.